# Website not appearing on search engines

Tags: html, seo, pagerank

It was made on a wordpress clean installation as all the websites I have made, but this one has been online for months and there is no registry for example on google. the url doesn't even appear on google, so it's not even a bad seo programation...

All websites I have made just like this appear on google, so I don't know what's happening.

I used to have a robots.txt with allow all but I removed it since it didn't make anything...

It had this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you signed up with Google Webmasters to try and diagnose the problem? http://www.google.com/webmasters/

Comment: When youinstall wordpress it could be that you blocked out the search engine(Could be done by a meta tag). Dit you check this?

Comment: On the wordpress admin, I have already checked "Allow search engines to index this site."

Comment: I will check that Pekka, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by following the official Google guides:

Go through the webmaster tools:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

and move on to the "here's what google looks for" guide:

http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Comment: it's not about that, it doesn't even appear the link on google even if you type it... that guide it's about optimization, but that is not the problem right now... it's like the site it's blocked or something

Comment: check the answer again, the guides will get you well along your way